# recursive function in C

Tags: c, recursion

This is a recursive function to calculate the fraction in the picture. but this program crashes for n >= 6. I understand there is a problem with stack overflow, but how to fix it?

*n* passed in the third parameter *k*

*sqrt(b[k--])*: it should calculate the square root of *b[k]*, reduce *k* by 1, and transfer reduced *k* to *dod*

[picture with task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybLTF.jpg)

```
float dod(int *a, int *b, int k){
if (k == 1)
    return (a[1] * a[1]) / sqrt(b[1]);
return a[k] * a[k] / (sqrt(b[k--]) + dod(a, b, k));}
```

Comment: Where is `n` in the program anywhere? Do you mean `k`?

Comment: `a[k] * a[k] / (sqrt(b[k--]) + dod(a, b, k))` is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: The problem is that `+` operator does not define a sequence point. So you can't be sure that `k--` will be evaluated before call to `dod`

Comment: Which 'n' is >= 6??

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya . . . or the numerator calculation `a[k] * a[k]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes ofcourse but I figured that OP is getting confused that `k--` should decrement k and he will be fine in the call to `dod`, so I clarified that.

Comment: If this crashes it is probably because `dod` is passed wrong arguments. So we are missing the remaining of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C array index start at 0. So your code should probably read:

```
float dod(int *a, int *b, int k)
{
    if (k == 1)
        return (a[0] * a[0]) / sqrt(b[0]);
    return a[k-1] * a[k-1] / (sqrt(b[k-1]) + dod(a, b, k-1));
}
int *a, *b;
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    b = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
    printf("%f", dod(a, b, n));
    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: the program at the end gives the result and only after that crashes. and  everything works on ideone.com

Comment: Show us how you call `dod`. Here it works fine. The error is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Same thing in your calling code: array starts at 0. I edited to correct it.

Comment: yep it really works, thanks.
but i wanna understand why my code doesnt work. it showed the result and after that crashed

Comment: Your code crashed because `scanf("%d", &a[n])` wrote to memory that was not given to you (outside of the area you malloced) and used for other things. From then on all odds are off. If you want to use 1 based arrays — which you should *not* because it will be all the world against you — you should call malloc with on extra element as in `malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  float dod(int *a, int *b, int k){ 
if (k == 1) 
return (a[1] * a[1]) /sqrt(b[1]); 
else 
return a[k] * a[k] / (sqrt(b[k]) + dod(a, b, k-1));}
```

Did you try this?

Comment: Is the a[k] from a[0] till a[n-1] or a[1] till a[n] ?

Comment: [1/2]
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float dod(int *a, int *b, int k){
    printf("\n%f -- %f\n",(pow(a[k],2) ),(pow(b[k],0.5) ));
    if (k == 1)
        return (pow(a[k],2) ) / (pow(b[k],0.5) );
    return (pow(a[k],2) ) / ((pow(b[k],0.5) ) + dod(a, b, k-1));
}
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int * a = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)*n));
    int * b =(int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)*n));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }
    float x = dod (a,b,n-1);
    printf("\n%f\n",x);   
}`

Comment: from a[1] till a[n]

Comment: [2/2] I don't see an error for n=10 I mean _k_ <-- [1,9]
`10
12
23
32
543
654
754
585
5768
5768
965456
56
456
4
56
56
54
75
56
456
7

207936.000000 -- 2.645751

5625.000000 -- 7.483315

3136.000000 -- 7.348469

16.000000 -- 7.483315

3136.000000 -- 21.354157

33269824.000000 -- 982.576206

342225.000000 -- 75.947350

427716.000000 -- 27.459060

1024.000000 -- 23.302360

10808.805664`

Comment: Regarding this [code](http://ideone.com/1nE2Yk) How can you take the input of a[n],b[n] i.e., Index **n**? .You can only take input from index **0 to n-1**. It gives an error because at some point you are accessing some other data which isn't defined... @qeziz

Comment: Look at [this](https://repl.it/HKsn/0) . With the required changes in your code.@qeziz